# php updates database data only sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have to following form

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DBNAME) ;
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection))
{
echo "Nespojeno s MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM novinky";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
echo "<div id='newsbox'>";
while($zaznam = mysqli_fetch_row($result)): 
echo "<form class='newsholder'>";   
echo "<input id='displaynadpis' value='$zaznam[1]'>";   
echo "<input id='displaybold' value='$zaznam[2]'>"; 
echo "<textarea id='displaytext'>$zaznam[3]</textarea>";    
echo "<div class='buttonsholder'>";
echo "<button class='deletebutton'>Smazat</button>";
echo "<button class='updatebutton'>Upravit</button>";
echo "<input id='prime'  type='hidden' attr='id' value='$zaznam[0]'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";    
echo "</form>";
endwhile;

echo "</div>";

mysqli_close($connection);
```

that displays data from the database in order to update them upon the .updatebutton click.
The data is passed by jquery ajax

```
$('.updatebutton').on('click', function(){

var idVal = $(this).closest('.newsholder').find('#prime').val();
var displaynadpisVal = $(this).closest('.newsholder').find('#displaynadpis').val();
var displayboldVal = $(this).closest('.newsholder').find('#displaybold').val();
var displaytextVal = $(this).closest('.newsholder').find('#displaytext').val();

alert(displaynadpisVal);

$.ajax({url:"updaterecord.php",
type:"POST",
cache:false,
data:{id: idVal, displaynadpis: displaynadpisVal, displaybold: displayboldVal, displaytext: displaytextVal}

}); });
```

to the php script

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DBNAME) ;

if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection))
 {
  echo "Nespojeno s MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$id = $_POST['id'];
$updatenadpis = $_POST['displaynadpis'];
$updatetextbold = $_POST['displaybold'];
$updatetext = $_POST['displaytext'];


echo $updatetext;

$sql = "UPDATE novinky SET nadpis='$updatenadpis',
                         textbold='$updatetextbold',
                         text='$updatetext'



WHERE id = '$id'" 
   ;


$retval = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
 die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";

mysqli_close($connection);
```

to update the database. The problem is, that it only works sometimes, but in about 70% of cases it doesn't make any change. The data is stored in js variables just fine, when tested by alert(), they exist everytime. So the problem must be in the mysqli_query() possibly? Or the AJAX method? I have tried a lot of options and recommendations from other posts but no luck. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Try to use prepared statements and catch exceptions. You will have a starting point.

Comment: Can you please check your browser firebug or inspect element and check your ajax response and post here if any error comes in that response.

Comment: The status code is: 200 OK on the ajax post method.... and I'm not quite sure how to construct the prepared statement....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest problem here is fact that you are passing raw user input to query. Assigning it to variable doesn't change anything!

You should filter everything received from user and use prepared statements to be sure that you are safe.

Also don't use `mysqli_connect_error()` to check query errors. Use `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do the prepared statement but not sure about the proper construction. In the next comment is what I have done...

Comment: $stmt = $sql->prepare("UPDATE novinky SET nadpis=?,
        textbold=?,
        text=?
        


WHERE id = ?")
       ;

$stmt->bindParam('sss', $updatenadpis, $updatetextbold, $updatetext

);

$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();